# xpath exclude certain child element with class

Tags: html, xpath, web-scraping

I have a html structure which for instance could look like below in a simplified version. I want to exclude the yarpp-related div from the xpath content. Here is what i'm using at the moment:

```
//div[@class='entry-content']
```

How can i exlude the yarpp-related div?

html structure

```
<div class="entry-content">
    <div class="yarpp-related">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you mean you wish to skip the outer `div` if it has a child  `div` with `class="yarpp-related"`?

Comment: i don't want the yarpp-related div and the inner content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XPath is for selection, not manipulation.  You can select nodes as they exist in an XML document, but you cannot transform those nodes.

In your case, if your XML document includes this node,

```
<div class="entry-content">
    <div class="yarpp-related">
    </div>
</div>
```

you can select the `entry-content` `div` via `//div[@class='entry-content']`, but the selected node will appear as it appears in the source XML, that is, ***with*** the child `yarpp-related` `div` node.

If you want to manipulate or transform a node selected via XPath (to exclude its children elements) you'll have to use the hosting language (XSLT, Python, Java, C#, etc) to manipulate the selection.

Comment: So for instance using php i could remove it?

Comment: Yes.  From PHP you could select the node using XPath and then remove its children via PHP.

Comment: okay  i just thought that xpath had some kind of exclude function, but i will take a look at that. thank you for taking your time leading me in the right direction

Answer (score 3):

```
//div[@class='entry-content'][not(contains(div/@class, 'yarpp-related'))]
```

or

```
//div[@class='entry-content']/div[not(contains(@class, 'yarpp-related'))]
```

Comment: hmm it seems to include the yarpp-related class anway

Comment: No, I don't think so: http://www.utilities-online.info/xpath/?save=25cad4d4-4814-4f8f-8b89-84d789fc953d-xpath#.VVYyZflVhBc

Comment: The first one doesn't work here, but the second one does. Good enough; I was ready to give up on that.

Comment: **This fails to answer OP's actual question:** The first merely selects `entry-content` `div` elements that lack child `yarpp-related` `div` elements, which is the best one can do with XPath alone.  (The second is completely off-base as it selects `entry-content` child `div` elements.) OP's actual question was how to remove that inner `yarpp-related` `div`, not just how to avoid selecting `entry-content` `div` that already exclude it.   The correct answer is that OP's goal cannot be achieved via XPath alone.