# How to get partial text of an element using Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, xpath-1.0

I have this HTML:

```
<div id="msg">

  <b>text1</b>
  <br>
  text2 <b>text3</b> text4

  <ul class="list">
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
  </ul>

  text5

</div>
```

I want to extract from `div[@id = 'msg']` the text before `ul`, using xpath.

Like `driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath")).getText()` -> `text1 text2 text3 text4`

It is possible or I should user another logic?

Comment: Your best bet is to get the `.innerHTML` from `#msg`, split it by the `UL` tag, and then strip out the HTML tags.

Comment: @JeffC how I use `.innerHTML` ? Can you give me a short example?

Comment: `driver.findElement(By.id("msg")).getAttribute("innerHTML");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per @kjhughes in [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30265455/xpath-exclude-certain-child-element-with-class), XPath is for selection, not manipulation. You can select nodes as they exist in an XML document, but you cannot transform those nodes.

In your case, if your XML document includes this node:

```
<div id="msg">
  <b>text1</b>
  <br>
  text2 <b>text3</b> text4
  <ul class="list">
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
  </ul>
  text5
</div>
```

You can select the `<div`> node through `//div[@id='msg']`, but the selected node will appear as it appears in the source XML, that is, with the child with *class* as `list` within the `<ul>` node.

If you want to manipulate or transform a node selected via XPath (to exclude its children elements) you'll have to use the hosting language (XSLT, JavaScript, Python, Java, C#, etc) to manipulate the selection.

---

### Solution

To extract the texts individually you can use the following solution:

```
WebElement myElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='msg']"));
String text1 = myElement.findElement(By.xpath("./b")).getAttribute("innerHTML");
String text2 = ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript('return arguments[0].childNodes[3].textContent;', myElement).toString();
String text3 = ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript('return arguments[0].childNodes[4].textContent;', myElement).toString();
String text4 = ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript('return arguments[0].childNodes[5].textContent;', myElement).toString();
String text5 = ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript('return arguments[0].lastChild.textContent;', myElement).toString();
```

Comment: I want to use xpath. Your suggest get entire div because `@ul` mean attribute `ul` of  `div`.

Comment: Same. Your xpath now looking for div to not have `class='list'` :) Answer of Waqar Nadir is the nearest one, but still not the result I want.

Comment: This doesn't work. This gets the `DIV` that has an id `msg` that doesn't have the class 'list'... thats `<div id="msg">`... and it gets the entirety of the text inside that tag which is everything.

Comment: I use xpath and get all div : `text1 text2 text3 text4 ... ... ... text5` and If you try to understand logically `//div[@id='msg' and not(@class='list')]` -> get `div` with `id = msg` and `class != list`

Comment: @KunLun Checkout my updated answer and let me know the status.

Answer (score 0):

Just want to share another idea.

You can get the OuterHTML and then strip it till "ul" tag and then remove the html tags from the output. Now you can change the string as per your need.

I am almost able to get the text you are looking for, using javascript. Pasted it below for your reference, you can do the same in Java.

```
oHTML = document.querySelector("div#msg").outerHTML
oHTML.substring(0,oHTML.search('<ul')).replace(/<.*>/,'').replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, "").replace(/\n/g, " ").trim()
```

you can run this in the browser console to see the output. Below is the javascript output.

```
text1      text2 text3 text4
```